# Need to factorize$ x^7 - x$ to irreducible polynomials over $\operatorname{GF}(2)$

Tags: polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

Can some one help me with an easy method to solve this question?

> Factorize $x^7 - x$ to irreducible polynomials over $\operatorname{GF}(2)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using that modulo $\;2\;$ we have $\;(a+b)^2=a^2+b^2\;$ :

$$x^7-x=x(x^6-1)=x(x^3-1)^2=x(x-1)^2(x^2+x+1)^2$$

Of course, $\;-1=1\;$ so you can write $\;x-1\;$ or $\;x+1\;$ . It's the same.

Comment: Thank you for helping. How should we go if the field changes say x^8 -1 for GF(9)

Comment: Do it as far as you can over the integers, say: $$x^8-1=(x^4-1)(x^4+1)=(x^2-1)(x^2+1)(x^4+1)=(x-1)(x+1)(x^2+1)(x^4+1)$$ But there is a square root of $\;-1\;$ in $\;\Bbb F_9\;$ (why?) . What about a fourth root?

Comment: (1 + x) (2 + x) (x + α) (1 + x + α) (2 + x + α) (x + 2 α) (1 + x + 2 α) (2 + x + 2 α) is the answer but i dont know how to reach there

Comment: Observe that if $\;w\;$ is a root of $\;x^2+1\;$ ,then **also** $\;2w\;$ is a root, which gives us that in the above $\;a=w\;$ and we get the factors $\;x-a=x+2a\;,\;\;x-2a=x+a\;$ Check now that the other factors we haven't checked come from the factoring of $\;x^4+1\;$

Comment: how does x - a become x + 2a ?

Comment: @user2971393. $\;-1=2\pmod 3\;$ ....

Comment: Yes that makes sense but we are dealing with GF(9) thats my confusion.